# Verifying proper transfer of JSON packet to iOS device

Tags: c#, iphone

I was wondering what is an easy and good way to verify my packet was transferred to the iPad successfully?

What I thought I could do, is pass the file size with the JSON object on the server side, and verify it's the same size on the iPad.  On the server side, it's a rest service written in C#.  I know I can get the FileInfo(file).length that is being transferred.  However, on the iPad, because this packet is being serialized as JSON, my tab-delimited text file now has more characters in it.  So if I write that file to disk, the file is much larger than it originally was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it not work if you un-serialize it out of JSON format?  You should be able to get the original file back.

Rather than checking file length, you could generate a digest, e.g. MD5 or SHA1, to verify that the contents of the file are exactly the same.  But this still depends on getting the exact contents out of the JSON format and into the original format.

You could also generate the digest on the JSON packet server-side and compare that rather than comparing the plain file's digest.